# How to import large datasets into Google Colab?

Tags: colab, google

Does anyone know a (free) method for importing large datasets into Google Colab, of multiple GB? Github is severely limited, uploading a folder to google drive takes a long time.

Comment: A better option will be to use `wget` command. I have discussed various approaches [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/4-awesome-ways-of-loading-ml-data-in-google-colab-9a5264c61966).

Answer (score 2):

One option is that you can download the dataset into your system and save it in an easily accessible directory. Then, run the following codes:

```
from google.colab import files
```

```
data = files.upload()
```

After running the above line, you will get a **Choose File** button where you can directly browse your system and choose your file.

Added the screenshot for your reference:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Unfortunately this method also takes a lot of time to upload. I have a 25mb file that takes about 10 minutes to upload, forget about uploading in GB's.